# Force Windows 8 to use UMTS

Tags: windows-8, virtual-machine, lan, broadband, umts

My situation:

I am running (evaluating) Windows 8 (RTM) on my Laptop. 
I am connected to a LAN which has NO access to the internet (DEV-LAN). 
I am running a virtual machine (VMware Workstation) which is connected via Bridge Mode to the DEV-LAN. This virtual machine has no access to the internet.

Before, with Windows 7 I was able to connect the host via UMTS to the internet while the virtual machine still was connected to the DEV-LAN. So I could keep working within the virtual machine while doing research (MSDN, Google, Stackoverflow) in the internet on the host.

When I now connect the Windows 8 host to the mobile broadband, nothing changes in the runtime  behaviour. The whole Network communication is still running over DEV-LAN. Windows 8 tells me in the Network Sidebar that mobile broadband is connected, but it does not use it. When I remove the network plug of DEV-LAN, THEN the broadband connection will be used. But then obviously, I cannot work in my virtual machine, which depends on DEV-LAN.

Question:

Is there any switch in windows 8 that I can use to tell the system to use broadband over LAN, when available?

Thanks a lot!

Torsten

---

edit for the comment of pst: the following metrics are given

```
IPv4-Routentabelle
===========================================================================
Aktive Routen:
     Netzwerkziel    Netzwerkmaske          Gateway    Schnittstelle Metrik
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.23.1    192.168.23.12     25
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      77.24.97.50      77.24.97.49    296
```

Comment: It sounds like Windows 8 is just not using the correct DEFAULT ROUTE or DEFAULT GATEWAY (search terms) when the UTMS connection is available - perhaps it is given a lower metric score? I do not know the Windows 8 tooling; earlier version of windows had a `route` command (and also I think it could be set it the network adapter properties).

Comment: thanks, pst, for your comment. I added the metric score information in the post above. I will research how to change it. If you have any hint, feel free to help on ;-)

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27994/how-to-change-the-priority-of-wiredwireless-network-cards-in-windows/ - not sure if it works with Windows 8.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/77822/how-to-tell-windows-7-to-ignore-a-default-gateway - how to remove default GW across network (look at non-accepted answer at bottom, accepted answer changes metric assignment); again, not sure if it works with Windows 8 :-)

Comment: the change of the metric at howtogeek may work. All Dialogs are still the same, but the changed metric does not apply... Its too late now in my timezone for further experiments ;-) I will continue on monday. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think it is not as easy as I hoped. When setting the metric score of the UMTS card to a number of 5, then the virtual machine gets no "physical" connect to the DEV-LAN. Maybe it tries a connection over the UMTS adapter, which is not connected. I will try tomorrow in detail...

Comment: Another way, the same result :-( I found out that there is a much easier way than manually configure the metric: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894564/EN-US "How to change the binding order of network adapters". It would be great if it would work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally works :-)
I set the metric of my LAN-Adapter to 999 and everything is as I want it to be.

Any change of the UMTS Adapter to a *lower* metric was unsuccessful. 
Even when I set the metric to 1 or 5 or 10, netstat /rn told me a metric > 50.

So when I cannot lower the one metric, I have to raise the other one ;-)

The metric can be easily changed like follows:

1. System Settings
2. Network and Internet
3. Network Connections
4. Ethernet -> Context Menu -> Properties
5. Select Internet Protocol (v4) -> Properties
6. Advanced
7. Automatic Metric off and manually set to 999